# Removing CSS Style In Irregular Tags Content

Tags: jquery

I have this jquery :

```
$(".note-editable").bind("paste", function() {
    var elem = $(this);
    setTimeout(function() {
        var prod_desc_text = elem.html(); <<< this can contains <p>, <span>, <h1>, <h2>, etc tags with style attribute

        prod_desc_text = prod_desc_text.$("*").removeAttr("style"); <<< I want to remove all style attribute 

        elem.html("");
        elem.append(prod_desc_text);
    }, 100);
});
```

How to remove all `style` attribute within `prod_desc_text` variable?

I tried with : `prod_desc_text = prod_desc_text.$("*").removeAttr("style");` but it seems my selection isn't working.

thank you very much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's a piece of HTML string. You cannot use jQuery stuff on strings. Convert it to HTML Element and then apply jQuery on it. You need to try this:

```
$(prod_desc_text).find("*").removeAttr("style").html();
```

**Snippet** using another method.

```js
$(function () {
  var prod_desc_text = '<p style="margin: 0;">Hello</p><p>Hello</p><div style="text-align: center;">Hello</div>';
  var a = $("<div />", {html: prod_desc_text});
  console.log(a.find("*").removeAttr("style").end().html());
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```